# Simperium crashes on initWithViewController because of sp_md5StringFromData

Tags: simperium

When using Simperium in my app, the app quits with this error:

```
+[NSString sp_md5StringFromData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x19fdfd8
```

I've debugged the code enough to know that it's crashing in the `[[Simperium alloc] initWithViewController:controller]` method, in the following code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NotesViewController *controller = (NotesViewController *)[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] ;    

self.simperium = [[Simperium alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self.simperium startWithAppID:@"my-app-ID-goes-here"
                            APIKey:@"the-API-key-would-go-here"
                             model:[self managedObjectModel]
                           context:[self managedObjectContext]
                       coordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

*I've concealed the AppID and API Key --- that's not a bug! :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A required category for NSString isn't being loaded. This will happen if you forget to add `-ObjC` to "Other Linker Flags" under the build settings for your project. If you add that flag and run it again, I think you'll have better luck.